# Ajax call works on cordova but doesn't work on ionic react capacitor

Tags: reactjs, ajax, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

```
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IonApp, IonButton, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import Home from './pages/Home';

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';

import axios from 'axios';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
const App: React.FC = () => {

  let configAxios: object = {
    // responseType: 'document', 
    // headers: {
    //   // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    //   'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    // },
    data: { pToken: token}
  }

  const makeAxiosCall = () => {
    
    // axios.get(url, configAxios)
    // .then( (response) => {
    //  console.log(response);
    //   console.log("Sucesso");
    // })
    // .catch((err) => {
    //  console.log(err)
    // })

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      // url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
      url: url,
      //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // we are sending in JSON format so we need to specify this
      dataType: "text", // the data type we want back.  The data will come back in JSON format
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("Funcionou");
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(err){
        console.log( "ERROR", err );
        alert("Erro");
      }
     });
  }

  return (
  <IonApp>
    <IonButton onClick={makeAxiosCall}>
      Web Service
    </IonButton>
  </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When I try to make this ajax call to the url it doesn't work just gives me an error and doesn't specify it. But when I do the ajax call to typicodes it returns a valid response and falls in the success function. Why it doesn't work with my url that is a web service?
The url works on cordova but not on this project that is ionic react and capacitor.

The error that shows with ajax:

[image: Error]

The error that shows with axios:
[image: Error]

Comment: why are you using jquery in react project?

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: I tried with axios but it didn't work so I tried using ajax

Comment: Both are making an HTTP request under the hood, so it shouldn't matter. But not a good idea to use jQuery in a React project. Since you're using Capacitor, you might want to try and use this lib for http request: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http